# How to pay Chinese customs duties?

Tags: usa, china, customs-and-immigration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bringing items into China for a friend - what to expect at customs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/bringing-items-into-china-for-a-friend-what-to-expect-at-customs)

Based on the answers to [What to expect at Chinese customs when bringing in items for friends who live there?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3763/82), it looks like I will have to pay customs duties on a couple of items that I am taking with me to China.

Having never had to deal with this before, I'm not certain what to expect:

- What is the Chinese duty tax rate for US citizens?
- Can I pay the duty tax in US Dollars or with a credit card, or will I need to acquire Renminbi before I arrive?